# How to measure query executing time in apache derby?

Tags: derby

I am new to apache derby. I want to measure the time that takes to execute a query. How can I measure time ?

Comment: Is your query issued by a program? Call `System.currentTimeMillis` or `Instant.now()` before and after you call `Statement.executeQuery`.

Comment: No, I just used "ij" to execute my queries. Just wanted to know is there are any inbuilt way inside the derby to measure the time ?

Comment: Yes, there's a **vast** amount of Derby functionality for analyzing query performance, though a lot of this is pretty advanced and maybe a challenge for someone who is new to Derby. But, start here: https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips